# My StreamReader code is reading only every other line c#

Tags: c#, streamreader

This is my solved program that will read a text file with delimiters and transfer the data to a table using datagridview.

Now I'm having a hard time because the while loop is only reading every other line.

This is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextReader tr = new StreamReader("aplusixdata.txt");
    string[] columns = {"School","Room No.","Student No.","Excercise No.","Problem No.",
                                   "Nth Problem Taken","Date","Time","Excercise Degree",
                                   "Action No.","Duration","Action","Error","Etape",
                                   "Expression","Etat","Cursor Location","Selection",
                                   "Equivalence","Resolution","Empty"};

    while (tr.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        int i = 0;                
        char[] delimiterChar = { ';' };
        string words = tr.ReadLine();
        text = words.Split(delimiterChar);
        DataRow row = t.NewRow();
        foreach (String data in text)
        {
            //System.Console.WriteLine(data);
            System.Console.WriteLine(i);
            row[columns[i]] = data;
            i++;
        }
        t.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling `ReadLine` twice on every iteration - once here:

```
while (tr.ReadLine() != null)
```

and once here:

```
string words = tr.ReadLine();
```

Change it to only read once per iteration:

```
char[] delimiterChar = { ';' };

string words;
while ((words = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    int i = 0;                
    text = words.Split(delimiterChar);
    ...
}
```

(Note that I've also pulled the creation of the `char[]` out of the loop - there's really no need to do *that* on every iteration. I'd personally make it a private static variable.)

A couple of other style points:

- Where is your `text` variable declared? Why not declare it in the loop itself?
- I would elide the declaration and first assignment of `row`:

  ```
  DataRow row = t.NewRow();
  ```

EDIT: As per shahkalpesh's answer, you *really* should use a `using` statement to make sure your reader is closed at the end.

Comment: Oh my bad on row... the error first pointed that the NullReferenceException was at that line so I took it out then placed it back again. Thanks this was very very helpful. :D

Answer (score 3):

That is because you are making a call to `ReadLine` twice.

A better way could be:
`while (!tr.EndOfStream)`

EDIT: It will be better to have the code surrounded by `using` clause.

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("aplusixdata.txt"))
{
  //.. your code here that reads the file line by line
}
```

Comment: Except that it requires changing the variable type to `StreamReader`, making it less general. If you're going to read a line anyway, IMO it makes sense to have that one `ReadLine` call detect end-of-data as well.

Comment: @leppie: I will delete the answer, if you'd like. I didn't see Jon's reply when I was writing this :)